# Nginx Friendly URL File Extension

Tags: php, regex, nginx, seo, friendly-url

I got my nginx.conf file:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|swf)$ {
   expires 7d;
}

location /
{
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite
}


location @rewrite
{
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6 break;
}
```

I want to replace friendly-url (generated by php file) link with seo optimised one.

```
https://example.com/gallery/basic-friendly-url-here/photoid
```

File extension is required by search engine, so I need to make it look like this:

```
https://example.com/gallery/basic-friendly-url-here/photoid.png
```

Unfortunately, I can't do it this way, because nginx throws 404 error.

Any ideas how to redirect link https://example.com/gallery/* into executable php file located in /vendor/mindgoner/script.php and handle seo url as GET parameter, instead of path?

Comment: Who is the author of this nginx config? Who is the author of the backend `index.php` script? The whole task can be solved (and better to be solved) in a completely different way, if an `index.php` script logic is under your control. Regex used for the `rewrite` rule, while being workable, is **extremely** ineffective.

Comment: Nginx is made by person who is not working on this project anymore. In index.php, there is a simple controller, that manage GET parameters. The ideology is quite simple:
`https://example.com/here/are/parameters`, where `$_GET['a'] = "here"`, `$_GET['b'] = "are"` and `$_GET['c'] = "parameters"`. 
In my case, I use "gallery" as `$_GET['a']`, seo-url as `$_GET['b']` and gallery photo id as `$_GET['c']`.
To be honest, I'd code this in another way, but the whole system works like this since years. I know how to to work this out on apache, but my boss build it on nginx. That's why I ask for help.

Comment: I understand the ideology, however I'd code it in a completely different way too, splitting the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` string in parts using the `/` character as a delimiter. And how do you want that `/gallery/basic-friendly-url-here/photoid.png` request URI appear to the PHP script? The same way like `a=gallery&b=basic-friendly-url-here&c=photoid.png`?

Comment: In fact, I would be happy to receive `[this]` from `https://example.com/gallery/[this]` in GET method. Sometimes `[this]` has a dot in it, and it throws 404 error. I would like `[this]` to be treated as variable, not as a path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if there are no physical directory named `gallery` under your web server root directory, you can use the following:

```
location ^~ /gallery/ {
    rewrite ^/gallery/(.*) /index.php?gallery_item=$1 last;
}
```

Then the requested filename will be available inside your `index.php` as the `$_GET['gallery_item']`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I was so close, because I've tried `rewrite ^/(.*)` instead `rewrite ^/gallery/(.*)`. Anyways, thank you very much.